# Saving project with Cucumber Steps definitions as java library

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have project with Cucumber Steps definitions, and want to save it as library to make it usable in other test projects. What will be best way to do this?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/wiki/Reusing-Of-Step-Definitions-From-External-Class-Path-Dependencies(JAR-POM...etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose Maven's "Preferred way" of creating a jar containing test classes:
[link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)